# Changing DataGrid's selectedItem breaks binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, selecteditem

I got an annoying problem with my bindings and I can't find out what I'm doing wrong.

I have a datagrid bound to an ObservableCollection and a Label which is bound to the Name of the SelectedItem of the datagrid.

When I change now the Name of the selected Item programmatically with a button, this somehow brakes the binding between the label and the name of the SelectedItem. Through testing I found out that it has something to do with the overridden Equals and GetHashCode methods of my Class person.

I broke everything down to a small example:

XAML-Code:

```
<Window x:Class="IndependentTesting.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.RowSpan="2" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="button1_Click" Grid.Row="1" />
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1, Path=SelectedItem.Name}" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ObservableCollection<Person> persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        persons.Add(new Person("p1"));
        persons.Add(new Person("p2"));
        dataGrid1.DataContext = persons;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGrid1.SelectedItem != null && dataGrid1.SelectedItem is Person)
        {
            ((Person)dataGrid1.SelectedItem).Name = "changed";
        }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Person))
        {
            return false;
        }
        Person p = (Person)obj;
        return (Name == null && p.Name == null) || (Name != null && Name.Equals(p.Name));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name == null ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

If I run this code and select one of the two persons and then press the button the binding brakes and regardless what I select afterwards the label stays the same. What am I missing?

Comment: Likely, your binding does not break -- it just does not get notified that the *Person.Name* property has been changed... implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for your Person class, and raise the event declared by this interface (PropertyChanged) whenever the Name property is being changed (i.e., in the setter of Person.Name). However, when selecting other persons on the datagrid the binding for the label should still update, hmm...

Comment: Okay, it is not the data binding that breaks. The selection of the datagrid (or rather the Selector type from which DataGrid inherits) gets confused and does not update the SelectedItem property anymore...

Comment: That seems to be the problem, it is not the binding it is the Selector. Thank you for your hint, I tested it and after clicking the button and then clicking an element in the datagrid there are 2 SelectedItems (also if Mode=Single !!! which should not happen regarding to the Documentation). So I think this is definitely a bug of Datagrid. The question is now how to implement a workaround. Can I change the Selector of the Datagrid somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selector internally uses **`InternalSelectedItemsStorage`** which **holds ItemInfo for SelectedItems**.

When any item is selected, it tries to remove the previously selectedItem from the SelectedItems collection and corresponding ItemInfo from InternalSelectedItemsStorage. Then, add selected item entry in SelectedItems collection and also its ItemInfo in InternalSelectedItemsStorage.

*(**Note** - This is my assumption by looking at stack trace if I put break point on GetHashCode() method. You can use reflector to peek into the actual code of dataGrid if you want)*.

> **Issue** - You change Name of SelectedItem property on button click. *(property playing vital role in calculating HashCode for an object.)* And
>   when you change selection in dataGrid, it tries to find entry in
>   InternalSelectedItemsStorage which it can't find because ItemInfo
>   hashcode has changed which it was earlier when item was stored in it.
>   Hence, it never gets removed from the selectedItems collection. Hence,
>   no binding updates in label.

---

If you replace GetHashCode() method to this, you will see sample works fine:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return Name == null ? 0 : base.GetHashCode();
}
```

---

I can suggest a workaround for this is to *set SelectedItem to null before updating it's Name so that it gets removed from InternalSelectedItemsStorage. Set back the SelectedItem to same value once you are done with updating Name property*.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGrid1.SelectedItem != null && dataGrid1.SelectedItem is Person)
    {
        Person selectedItem = (Person)dataGrid1.SelectedItem;
        dataGrid1.SelectedItem = null;
        selectedItem.Name = "changed";
        dataGrid1.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
    }
}
```

Also, you need INPC which I am assuming you already know why it is required.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `Person` class in order to propagate the change notifications to the UI

The `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is used to notify clients, typically binding clients, that a property value has changed.

example

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Person))
        {
            return false;
        }
        Person p = (Person)obj;
        return (Name == null && p.Name == null) || (Name != null && Name.Equals(p.Name));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name == null ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

more on [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

Comment: I didn't implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in my example because I wanted to provide a minimal example where this weird behavior occurs. The INotifyPropertyChanged interface doesn't change anything, the weird behavior still occurs with the only difference that now the label field is one time updated with changed after clicking the button but after this it doesn't change anymore if I click the other element.